# setTimeout issue, there is no time out

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

sorry, but this isn't easy for me....!
I want a div to show after several seconds,after a click on a button.
It is showing, but right when you click, there is no delay. What am i doing wrong here?

```
$('div.skill').hide();
$('.btn_2').click(function(e){              
        showSkills ();
      });
function showSkills(){
    alert("Hello")
};
setTimeout ( "showSkills()", 3000 );
```

Tnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close.

1. The `setTimeout` call should be inside of your click handler, not below it.
2. There is no need to pass the function name as a string.

This is the proper way to achieve what you're after:

```
$('div.skill').hide();
$('.btn_2').click(function (e) {
    setTimeout(showSkills, 3000);
});

function showSkills() {
    alert("Hello")
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You are calling showSkills in your button click handler, move your setTimeout line into your click handler instead

```
$('div.skill').hide();
$('.btn_2').click(function(e){              
        setTimeout ( showSkills, 3000 );
      });
function showSkills(){
    alert("Hello")
};
```

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
setTimeout (function(){ "showSkills()"}, 3000 );
```

Comment: Although it will work, it makes the code harder to read (and maintain)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div.skill').hide();

$('.btn_2').click(function(e){              
        setTimeout(showSkills, 3000);
});

function showSkills(){
    alert("Hello")
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('div.skill').hide();
$('.btn_2').click(function(e){              
    setTimeout (showSkills, 3000 );
});
function showSkills(){
    alert("Hello")
};
```